# How to load all items from a template with pyQGIS in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, qgis-2.6, template

Since QGIS 2.6, the LoadFromTemplate method seems not work any more (or works differently?)

This is my code to add items in my composer from a template :

```
self.composition = self.composerView.composition()
file1=QtCore.QFile('ComposerTemplate.qpt')
doc=QtXml.QDomDocument()
doc.setContent(file1, False)
self.composition.loadFromTemplate(doc, substitutionMap=None, addUndoCommands =False)
```

Up to 2.4 version, this code worked great.
But since the last QGIS update, nothing is imported from the template. I do not get either error messages

I've readen in QGIS changelogs, that the "Load from template" button is replaced by a "softer" "Add items from template" one. But it's in the GUI...
In the API doc, the LoadFromTemplate method is still present. And should still work?

Has someone an idea about what's happening?

Comment: LoadFromTemplate() works perfectly in QGIS 2.6.
My template had just a path problem.
Sorry for the noise.